# .htaccess - redirect all pages except for 1 page and another page depending on it's querystring

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just rebuilt and launched a site (we'll call it example.com) and assigned a subdomain of legacy.example.com to the old site.  I need to allow people to access their order history on the old site but I don't want them to be browsing the products and allowing access to the cart and checkout on the old site.  So I need to redirect everything except the login/logout pages, the account page, and the receipt page:

```
Login page = page.php?pg=extranet&mode=login  
Logout page = page.php?pg=extranet&mode=logout  
Account page = page.php?pg=extranet  
Order listing page = page.php?pg=extranet&mode=orderstatus  
Receipt page = receipt.asp
```

I've been messing with this for the better part of a day and have been all over the internet and back and can't find the magic combination of "and" and "or" for the condition.  Is it even possible or do I need to break it into multiple Condition/Rule sets?  How would I do that?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/receipt.asp [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page.asp [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^pg=extranet [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^pg=extranet&mode=login [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^pg=extranet&mode=logout [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^pg=extranet&mode=orderstatus [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please note that query string variables can appear in any order, so people can still access the page if they go to `page.php?mode=login&pg=extranet` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it other way round i.e. if input URL matched any of the above conditions when skip rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine On

# if login/logout/orderstatus don't do anything
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pg=extranet(&mode=(login|logout|orderstatus))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ - [L]

# if receipt page don't do anything
RewriteRule ^receipt\.php$ - [L,NC]

# otherwise redirect to new site
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: +1, yes very good simplification as always done by @anubhava.

Comment: That works!  Thank you! And now I've noticed it also excludes my css and js files that are needed for page display.  Oops!  How do I exclude them from being redirected also?  The files are in the /css and /js directories.

Comment: @jacouh: Thanks so much. Michelle: You can modify 2nd rule as: `RewriteRule ^receipt\.php|css/|js/ - [L,NC]` to skip css, js files